# Jenkins using File Parameter with MultiJob Project

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using the MultiJob Project in order to implement a process the runs every time there is a push to a certain Git branch.

How can I pass parameters between 2 different jobs (each job is located in a separate MultiJob Phase)

What i tried to do is:

Job A: (Run on the Master - windows)

echo 2 parameters into a new file (Called parameters.properties) that i placed in a shared location (not in the workspace of Job A)

so this file's contnet looks like:

```
currentBuild=2012-11-27_09-20-50 
currentBranch=master
```

Job B: (Run on a Linux Slave)

The option of "This build is parametrized" is on.

Added "File Parameter" and only the file name as I also set a custom workspace to the shared location where the file is located.

The i have a shell script that tries to use this parametrs but it doesnt get it.

Please Assist,

Doron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Solution:

1. in the MultiJob Main Project:

   - Set "This build is parametrized"

     Add 2 Text Parameters (different names since the Job Build is based on Jenkins variable  Build_Id which is changed and i want later to set the currentBuild to a constant value and not to a new one)

     - JobBuild
     - JobBranch
2. On each Job under each MultiJob Phase:

   - Add Predefined Parameters:

     - currentBuild=${JobBuild}
     - currentBranch=${JobBranch}

   untick the "Current job parameters"

   untick the Exposed SCM"