# How to configure Jenkins for MasterJob to pass git tag to child jobs, which execute in parallel?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, continuous-deployment

I've seen numerous questions on SO for similar issues, but I haven't found one that answers this question for me.

I'm looking for pretty much the simplest use case for parallel builds. I'd like to do the following:

```
Job1 (git commit no: abc123)
  |
  +------- SubJob1 (git commit no: abc123)
  |
  +------- SubJob2 (git commit no: abc123)
```

Both subjobs would be executed in parallel, and Job1 wouldn't complete until all subjobs finished.

Job1 gets executed by a git hook for a commit against any branch. At the moment the subjobs execute other commits instead of the exact one the parent job originally executed against.

Anyway to get this working?

As a bonus question, would it be possible for console output to be rolled up to the master job?

Thanks

Comment: Note that the client does not get the cloned files from the master, but clones on its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [MultiJob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) which allows you to trigger phases of jobs (subjob1 and subjob2) in addition to any standard job building steps you want in the main job (job1)

You can also pass parameters into the subjobs 
[Jenkins using File Parameter with MultiJob Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580023/jenkins-using-file-parameter-with-multijob-project)

---

EDIT the [git parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin) plugin may help to pass git revisions into jobs

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found is to use the MultiJob plugin with the Git Plugin.

So for the example in the question:

```
Job1 (git commit no: abc123)
  |
  +------- SubJob1 (git commit no: abc123)
  |
  +------- SubJob2 (git commit no: abc123)
```

When Job1 is triggered by your SCM, the [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) will save a few env variables including `GIT_COMMIT - SHA of the current, aka the commit that triggered the build`

You need to set which branches to build. Job1 will be triggered by your SCM so no need to set a branch or commit anywhere. In the multijob phase where you trigger SubJobs 1 and 2, under the **Advanced** options, choose **Add Parameters** and select **Pass-through Git Commit that was build** this will pass the sha of the commit that triggered Job1 to it's subjobs.

One last thing to get this working, in SubJob1 and SubJob2 under branch use the env variable `${GIT_COMMIT}`

Comment: Thank you for your accurate and complete answer.